# Decoding a string in python ... with _\x08__\x08_d\x08de\x08el\x08li\x08it\x08te\x08em in it 

Tags: python

I have some strings with all this kind of characters in it which also has normal letters ,
and i want to transform all the "wired" characters in they're normal representation .
So my question is : 
Is there a Pythonic way of doing this ?

I have a string for example this one :

```
Mymethods defined here:
 |  
 |  __add__(...)
 |      x.__add__(y) <==> x+y
```

This somehow has this output :

```
Mymethods defined here:\n 
 |  \n 
 |  _\x08__\x08_a\x08ad\x08dd\x08d_\x08__\x08_(...)\n 
 |      x.__add__(y) <==> x+y
```

Comment: Where do you have this string from?

Comment: Where are you getting these strings? They look like user input with all the backspace keypresses retained (`\x08` is backspace)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\x08` is the character representation for `backspace`.

So you should do a regexp replace

```
s/.\\x08//
```

That will remove all the `\x08`.

The `\n` is OK because it represents the end of the line.

Answer (score 8):

Some (very old) bits of software used to simulate bold text on printers (such as daisy wheel of golfball typewriters) but printing a character then a backspace then the same character again. It looks like your text is an example of this.

That means you need to remove not just the backspace but also the character following it:

```
>>> s = "_\x08__\x08_d\x08de\x08el\x08li\x08it\x08te\x08em in it"
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("\x08.", "", s)
'__delitem in it'
>>>
```

Better of course would be to fix whatever is generating this text and get it to generate **bold** text in a more useful manner.

Comment: What's generating it appears to be `pydoc`. However I don't get the `\b`s if I pipe its output to `subprocess` or a file.

Comment: That's right, when there's an output file it uses the 'plaintext' renderer instead of the 'text' renderer. It's not a clean interface as you have to call the non-exported functions directly to bypass the backspace bold.