# pydoc.render_doc() adds characters - how to avoid that?

Tags: python, character-encoding, pydoc

There are already some questions touching this but no one seems to actually solve it.

```
import pydoc
hlpTxt = pydoc.render_doc(help)
```

already does what I want! looks flawless when printed to the (right) console but it has those extra characters included:

```
_\x08_H\x08He\x08el\x08lp\x08pe\x08er\x08r
```

In Maya for instance it looks like its filled up with `◘`-symbols! While `help()` renders it flawless as well.

Removing `\x08` leaves me with an extra letter each:

```
__HHeellppeerr
```

which is also not very useful.
Someone commented that it works for him when piped to a subprocess or into a file. I also failed to do that already. Is there another way than

```
hlpFile = open('c:/help.txt', 'w')
hlpFile.write(hlpTxt)
hlpFile.close()
```

? Because this leaves me with the same problem. Notepad++ actually shows BS symbols at the places. Yes for backspace obwiously.

Anyway: There must be a reason that these symbols are added and removing them afterwards might work but I can't imagine there isn't a way to have them not created in the first place!

**So finally is there another `pydoc` method I'm missing? Or a `str.encode/decode` thing I have not yet seen?**

btw: I'm not looking for `help.__doc__`!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In python 2, you can remove the boldface sequences with `pydoc.plain`:

```
pydoc.plain(pydoc.render_doc(help))
```

```
>>> help(pydoc.plain)
Help on function plain in module pydoc:

plain(text)
    Remove boldface formatting from text.
```

In python 3 `pydoc.render_doc` accepts a `renderer`:

```
pydoc.render_doc(help, renderer=pydoc.plaintext)
```

Comment: Oh thanks so much! Incredible that this didn't show up already once!
You know whats the reason for the boldface formatting? Where is it used?

Comment: `less` displays it as bold. Try `python -c 'import pydoc; print pydoc.render_doc(pydoc)' | less`

Comment: hmm `less` is on linux?
As well as `>>> pydoc.plain?`? this yields a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` here on Win7.

Comment: But seems the boldface formatting is an extra nicety thats added by default. however: thanks a lot!

Comment: Um, on windows, there's `more`, but it doesn't treat that as bold, it just uses backspaces as intended and leaves normal text.

Comment: Oh, `?` is an ipython feature, sorry.